# Mini OS: Linking the compiled & assembled .o files

Tags: c, linker, operating-system, osdev

I'm trying to set up a working environment for assembling a bootloader and compiling and linking a simple kernel according to this page: [enter link description here](http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_bones)

So far everything went well, however I can't seem to work around this linker error:

```
C:\Users\----\Desktop\>ld -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin --oformat binary loader.o kernel.o
ld: cannot perform PE operations on non PE output file 'kernel.bin'.
```

The ld manual pages are in my opinion far too cryptic, and don't give any answers to this particular error message.

(I'm using Windows 7 64 bit)

Comment: Compiling a kernel on Windows is a hell though not impossible.

Comment: It's already compiled. My problem lies in the linking process.

Comment: Linking is a part of the compilation process, and it is the actual part I was mentioning by the word "hell". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through some of that OSDev article, but on a Linux machine. First, I should point out the second sentence of the preface states you should set up a [GCC Cross Compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) since you are on a Windows machine. But I believe specifically your error about the PE output file has to do with how `ld` is configured for Windows vs. Linux. Linux uses the ELF format for executable files, while Windows uses the PE format. These are two very different ways of representing a program/executable file. For the OSDev tutorial, you need to link the kernel in ELF format.

If you follow the article on setting up a GCC cross compiler, you should come to the section on building 'binutils.' Make sure your target is set up to be i586-elf. Continue following the article and you should be able to set up the linker `ld` to link to an ELF target instead of PE format.

Comment: Also one may user DJGPP utils. DJGPP toolkit contains such useful programs as ld86, as86 and gcc :-) And of course they are crosscompiling ready.